# How to update a Jenkins Properties Global Environment Variable from within a pipeline stage in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Wanting to update a ".env" properties value, so that the next execution has a new value.

```
loggingUtils.info("${env.testVar}")

env.testVar = "cat"

loggingUtils.info("${env.testVar}")
```

Currently what happens is if I configure the "env.testVar" to have a value of "dog" from within jenkins the print statements will be:

```
dog
cat
```

but the next time I execute I want it to be

```
cat
cat
```

However, it is always just

```
dog
cat
```

Is there a way to achieve setting the environment variables so that future builds will have the new variable? I would prefer to do this without a plugin if possible

Comment: pipeline `env` is a global variable within per pipeline running, it can't cross next running. Did your 'the next time i execute' means an new pipeline running?

Comment: How are you "configuring "env.testVar" to have a value of "dog" from within jenkins"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Builds (can be thought of as "instances of executions") in Jenkins are independent of each other.

If you are trying to tie builds together by transmuting information across builds I would encourage you to think about what you are really trying to do and suggest you might not doing Continuous Integration properly.

Each time you execute a build it starts from scratch.  Continuous Integration always starts with what's in source control. Nothing derived should be committed to source control.

I would suggest environment configuration should normally by stored in config files in source control and applied as appropriate via parameters to a build. (i.e what environment do I want to deploy a given build to?).